# Verb-agnostic matching in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

We can write

```rb
get '/foo' do
  ...
end
```

and

```rb
post '/foo' do
  ...
end
```

which is fine.  But can I combine multiple HTTP verbs in one route?

Comment: I give two solutions for you below. However, note this quote from the [linked discussion](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/253#issuecomment-1102620): _"I'm unaware of when it is correct for a GET or POST to the same path should result in identical behavior/responses. I've always found it to be the case that there is a minor difference in behavior, although the response may be the same. This is what templates/views are for. Any functionality they may share can easily be wrapped in a another method."_ Are you sure that you really want the exact same route for both `get` and `post`?

Comment: Thank you.  I would like still to be able to differentiate between the verbs inside the route.  It doesn't seem that multi_route supports this, but it must be trivial to add.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show that you can always use `request.env["REQUEST_METHOD"]` to determine what the verb is inside your route. The fact that you care makes it even more evident that you probably should have two separate routes with one or more shared helpers and views; however, the beauty of Sinatra is that there is no one right way...so enjoy! :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is possible via the [`multi-route` extension](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/blob/master/lib/sinatra/multi_route.rb) that is part of sinatra-contrib:

```
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/multi_route"
route :get, :post, '/foo' do
  # "GET" or "POST"
  p request.env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
end

# Or for module-style applications
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::MultiRoute
  route :get, :post, '/foo' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

However, note that you can do this simply yourself without the extension via:

```
foo = lambda do
  # Your route here
end
get  '/foo', &foo
post '/foo', &foo
```

Or more elegantly as a meta-method:

```
def self.get_or_post(url,&block)
  get(url,&block)
  post(url,&block)
end

get_or_post '/foo' do
  # ...
end
```

*You might also be interested in [this discussion on the feature](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/253).*

Answer (score 10):

FWIW, I just do it manually, with no helper methods or extensions:

```
%i(get post).each do |method|
   send method, '/foo' do 
       ...
   end
 end
```

Although if you're doing it a lot it of course makes sense to abstract that out.

Comment: This is the perfect solution by far. You remind me again that it's all Ruby and blocks :)

Answer (score 5):

Phrogz has a great answer, but if either lambdas or including sinatra-contrib isn't for you, then this meta method will achieve the same result as sinatra-contrib for your purposes:

```
# Provides a way to handle multiple HTTP verbs with a single block
#
# @example
#   route :get, :post, '/something' do
#       # Handle your route here
#   end
def self.route(*methods, path, &block)
    methods.each do |method|
        method.to_sym
        self.send method, path, &block
    end
end
```

If you're a little wary of being able to send arbitrary methods to `self`, then you can protect yourself by setting up a whitelist of allowed methods in an array, and then checking for the symbol's presence in the array.

```
# Provides a way to handle multiple HTTP verbs with a single block
#
# @example
#   route :get, :post, '/something' do
#       # Handle your route here
#   end
def self.route(*methods, path, &block)
    allowed_methods = [:get, :post, :delete, :patch, :put, :head, :options]
    methods.each do |method|
        method.to_sym
        self.send(method, path, &block) if allowed_methods.include? method
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a service-unavailable server that I managed to get on single line :)

```
require 'sinatra';set port: ARGV[0]||80;%w.get post put patch options delete..map{|v|send(v,'*'){503}}
```

I actually used this to test the behavior of some client code in the face of 503s.