# Handling 405's in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra if I create a simple endpoint such as:

```
post '/users' do 
    'posted'
end
```

`curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8080/users` returns a 404, when I would expect a 405.

I've looked through the documentation but not found anything. Before digging through the source code, does anyone know how to handle and return 405's in Sinatra? Sort of like the not found method:

```
not_found do
    'Not found - ' + request.path
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible without repeating yourself a lot. From looking through the Sinatra source code, the hash of routes has the verb as the key: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1513

It then looks up a route using that verb:
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L943

Which is not ideal and I would consider a weakness/bug in the framework as throwing a 405 when a verb isn't allowed is standard HTTP Spec.

I'll maybe raise an issue see what the contributors say. Ideally it would store routes by their url first, and then check the appropriate verb can be executed for a given url. This would make handling something as standard as a 405, much easier.

In fact I found an issue raised on github for the above:
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/24
As mentioned nearer the bottom, it's not currently handled and something they may work on for v2.0

Answer (score 3):

You got an 404 because sinatra can't find a get route /users. If you want return a custom error you may look at [Halt](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting)

## throw a error

The you can return a 405 on get /users like this:

```
get "/users" do
    halt 405
end
```

For catch multiple http verbs at once you can use [multi route](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/blob/master/lib/sinatra/multi_route.rb)

```
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/multi_route"
route :get, :post, '/foo' do
  # "GET" or "POST"
  p request.env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
end

# Or for module-style applications
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::MultiRoute
  route :get, :post, '/foo' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414395/verb-agnostic-matching-in-sinatra)

## handle errors

If you want handle error codes in sinatra you can simple do for 404 errors:

```
not_found do
  'This is nowhere to be found.'
end
```

In your case handle a 405 error:

```
error 405 do
  'Access forbidden'
end
```

Comment: So for every other verb that means I need to write a "halt 405"? That doesn't sound like an elegant solution. Technically, the resource/route exists, just the verb is wrong. Which is why I would expect a 405. There must be a better way to implement a catch all solution for 405's.

Comment: I think multi route is a elegant solution for your problem.

Comment: Hmmm, still not that elegant. It means I have to dirty my code with, route :get, :put :delete, :patch, :options, :and_so_on for every endpoint. But it's better than nothing, although I'd rather see if the core of the issue can be fixed.

Comment: you can may can catch some verbs with [Before](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#before) but it's still a lot repeating